# To fill combobox with multiple fields

Tags: c#, winforms, sqlite, listbox

I have this code:

```
private void comboBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (this.OpenConnection())
    {
        string query = "select username,group_id from students_groups where group_id ="+comboBox2.SelectedValue.ToString()+";";
        SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(query, myConn);
        DbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        ArrayList stud = new ArrayList();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            stud.Add(reader["username"].ToString());
        }
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        for (int i = 0; i < stud.Count; i++) {
            query = "select * from students_info where username='"+stud[i].ToString()+"';";
            SQLiteDataAdapter da = new SQLiteDataAdapter(query, myConn);
            da.Fill(ds, "sg");
            listBox1.DisplayMember = "firstname";
            listBox1.ValueMember = "username";
            listBox1.DataSource = ds.Tables["sg"];
        }
        this.CloseConnection();
    }
}
```

It works, but i need to fill the combobox with values from two columns: "firstname" and "lastname".
So this line:
       `listBox1.DisplayMember = "firstname";`
needs to be changed somehow.
Some ways are possible, but in that case i lose the ValueMember in listbox which i also need to keep.
How to insert two column values in listbox not losing the ValueMember?

P.S. There are some similar examples in here, but none of them fit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use sql query to slove it.

```
 select (' '+FisrtName + LastName)
  from student_groups
  for xml path('')
  where UserName='/*Some thing in here*/'
```

So, you`ll have a table with columns like FistName LastName